# Populate drop-down with observable array having structures

Tags: knockout.js

I want to switch image with drop-down box.
The drop-down contains names and should send an URL to the image. (URLs are not visible in the drop down)

I've found this example in the docs:

```
<select data-bind="options: optionValues, value: selectedOptionValue">
```

Bot it seems, like `optionValues` is observableArray containing only one value and `selectedOptionValue` is an observable getting the value selected in the drop box.

My observable array contain structures (hope it's the right expression in JS) looks like:

```
var PatternExample = function (type, name, example_url) {
            this.type = type;
            this.name = name;
            this.example_url = example_url;        
        }
```

Where name should be displayed in the drop-down and example_url used for changing the image.

How could I define the data-binding in the select-element for this data?

**EDIT:**

Found the answer also in the docs:
*Example 3: Drop-down list representing arbitrary JavaScript objects, not just strings.*

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this use `optionsText` in your select binding

**view :**

```
<select data-bind="options:optionValues,optionsText:'name', value: selectedOptionValue"></select>

<img data-bind="attr:{src:selectedOptionValue().url}" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self=this;
    self.selectedOptionValue=ko.observable();
    self.optionValues = ko.observableArray([{'type':'','name':'imageone','url':'www.s.com'},{'type':'','name':'imagetwo','url':'www.s1.com'},{'type':'','name':'imagethree','url':'www.s2.com'}]);
    self.selectedOptionValue.subscribe(function(data){
    console.log(data) // check the output here map url as per your requirement 
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

working sample fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24712/)**

Comment: OK, thaks! I'll check now.